# reduce number of rows textarea for mobile version

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea in my form

```html
<textarea class="js-message" name="message" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
```

I set `rows="6"`, but I need to make it so that for screens below 767 it was `rows="3"`

The option I tried to do is just change the height for this field depending on the screen, but this is not what I need

Comment: You'll need to use `JavaScript` for this. You might listen for the window resize event and change the `rows` attribute once it reaches the desired value(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the textarea `rows` attribute, it would have to be done using Javscript since the CSS alternative is to adjust by height.

- Use [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) to the get width of the window to test against for mobile.
- Attach function to a window [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event to trigger code to change rows attribute

```js
function changeRows() {
    const textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    if (window.innerWidth <= 767) {
        textarea.setAttribute("rows", "3");
    } else {
        textarea.setAttribute("rows", "6");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", changeRows);
```

```html
<textarea class="js-message" name="message" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
```